# Beracha upon seeing a friend on a webcam

Tags: halacha, blessing, technology, shehecheyanu, friendship

The Shulchan Aruch (OC 225:1) rules:

> שולחן ערוך אורח חיים הלכות ברכת הפירות סימן רכה
>
> הרואה את חבירו
>   לאחר שלשים יום, אומר: שהחיינו, ואחר י"ב חדש מברך:  מחיה
>   מתים, והוא שחביב עליו הרבה ושמח בראייתו

My translation: "If one sees his friend after thirty days, he recites *'[Shehechiyanu](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehecheyanu)'*; after twelve months, he recites *'Mechaye Metim'*. This is if he is very beloved to him and becomes happy upon seeing him."

What if the two friends interacted over a webcam?

- Does that break the streak of not seeing each other?
- Can one make the beracha over webcam (i.e. if the webcam meeting was after 30 days of no contact)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rav Ovadia Yosef rules in Yechavveh Da'at 4:17 that one would not say a bracha upon seeing someone through video chat. However he does quote one opinion that even allows one to say it upon hearing their voice on the telephone but dismisses it as very unlikely AND because by matters of doubt with brachot we rule to not say the bracha. Depending on which one of these two reasons is the main one will determine if video chat will restart the 30 day count. It seems to me that he mainly is siding with the doubt concern and would thus insist on restarting the count after a video chat, but not after a telephone call.

---

Here is the relevant quote from the responsa:
ויש להסתפק בדין הרואה את חבירו לאחר שלשים יום בטלויזיא /בטלויזיה/ בשידור חי, אם יברך עליו שהחיינו, וראה בשו"ת בצל החכמה חלק ב' (סימן י"א), ובשו"ת באר משה חלק ב' (סימן ט' אות ג), שהרואה מלך בטלויזיא לא יברך שנתן מכבודו לבשר ודם.   ע"ש.   וכן כתב בפשיטות בשו"ת מנחת יצחק ח"ב (סימן פ"ד אות י').   ועיין בשו"ת משפטי צדק (סימן כ"ט), ובפתח הדביר (סימן רכ"ד סק"י).   ובמה שכתבתי בשו"ת יביע אומר חלק ו' (חלק אורח חיים סימן י"ב).   ומכל מקום ספק ברכות להקל.   והנה בשו"ת ים הגדול (סוף סימן כ"ד) כתב, שהשומע קולו של חבירו בטליפון /בטלפון/ או ברדיו (בשידור חי), מברך עליו שהחיינו אם עברו עליו שלשים יום שלא ראהו.   משום דמידי הוא טעמא אלא משום חביבות ושמחה, הכי נמי בשמיעת קולו שיודע משלומו נחשב כראיה, וכמו שכתוב וכל העם רואים את הקולות וכו'.   ע"ש.   ולדבריו כל שכן כשרואהו בטלויזיא (בשידור חי).   ואין דבריו מחוורים, ואין לנו להוסיף על מה שאמרו חכמים, שתפסו לשון הרואה, שרואהו במו עיניו ושמח בקרבתו אליו, אבל אין שמיעת קולו בכלל זה.‏

Answer (score 5):

It has been some time since I looked at the issue, but as I recall the practice is to not recite this blessing, at least not with shem u'malchus (mentioning G-d's name and kingship). This is, in my recollection, at least in part because the blessing was instituted when such journey's could mean that one's friend would not return alive and by seeing them you know that they have survived. In later generations when the danger was not as pressing and contact via post or the like was more feasible the wording of the blessing was not as relevant.

Certainly, regardless of the technical aspects of the halachah viewing one's friend by webcam removes the uncertainty about the fate of one's friend making the blessing's comparison to resurrection out of place, strengthening the established practice not to recite it in full.

See the [Mishneh Berurah 225:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=277) which, if I am reading it correctly (big if) mentions *Achronim* who rule that in a situation where one has received a letter or received word from someone who is familiar with their well-being then one makes the blessing. He concludes that we rule leniently with regard to a doubtfully necessary blessing, which I take to mean one would not make the blessing. It would seem though that since such contact *after* the 30days/12months would be sufficient to necessitate a blessing in those opinions then conversely *with in* that time period would be sufficient contact to make it unnecessary later, which also would make it a doubtful blessing.

Comment: What you are saying relates to the bracha of mechaye hameitim said after not seeing them for twelve months. For shehechiyanu, all achronim say that it is simply the pleasure of seeing someone you haven't seen in a while (with the notable exception of the Mishna Berura who connects the two dinim without source or precedent)

Comment: @Yirmeyahu I challenge you to find _any_ achron that the mishna berura is basing himself on. I can't. And neither could Rav Ovadya Yosef (and that is saying something!!!) It's either a taut sofer or he made it up (I've seen both suggested). The aruch hashulcham, rav ovadya yosef and all other achronim hold that knowledge of his well being is only relevant for the bracha of mechaye hameitim.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu From the teshuva I referenced in my answer;  ואמנם ראיתי להמשנה ברורה (סימן רכ"ה סק"ב) שכתב, שיש דעות באחרונים, אם נתקבל ממנו מכתב בתוך שלשים יום או שאנשים הודיעוהו משלומו, אם יברך שהחיינו, וספק ברכות להקל.   ע"כ.   אולם במחכ"ת **לא דק שפיר**, והמעיין באחרונים ישר יחזו פנימו שלא נחלקו אלא לגבי ברכת מחיה המתים לאחר י"ב חודש, אבל לגבי ברכת שהחיינו אע"פ שקיבל ממנו מכתבים ושמע מטוב שלומו בתוך שלשים יום, לכל הדעות צריך לברך עליו שהחיינו, כשרואהו לאחר שלשים יום, שאינה דומה שמיעה לראיה, שההתפעלות וההתרגשות הנפשית תהיה בראיית חבירו פנים אל פנים ביתר שאת ויתר עוז

Comment: .   [וכן ראיתי לידידי הרה"ג רבי שריה דבליצקי שליט"א בספר זה השלחן (סימן רכ"ה), שהעיר כן על דברי המשנה ברורה הנ"ל, שלענין ברכת שהחיינו **אין כאן מחלוקת כלל** שצריך לברך גם אם קיבל ממנו מכתבים בתוך שלשים יום, **ושיש לתקן במשנה ברורה** על פי האמור.   וכן כתב בשו"ת יין הטוב (סוף סימן מ"ט).   ע"ש]  @Vram Courtesy ping!

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked long before the advent of webcams.  [The Steipler said that since telephones keep the world connected, one should not recite it.](http://revach.net/article.php?id=4171)

Comment: All this shows is that people take the Mishna Berura [too seriously](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14372/beracha-upon-seeing-a-friend-on-a-webcam/14378#comment26419_14374) sometimes. Also, can you help me locate this inside? 1:93 of what book?

Comment: @DoubleAA, See the comment by Shalom Spira on February 1, 2011 at 3:36 pm [on this Hirhurim post on the subject](http://torahmusings.com/2011/02/reuniting-with-friends). "In Contemporary Halakhic Problems II, in the chapter on Entebbe, RJDB cites ROY to the effect that we no longer recite the blessings of “Shehechiyanu” or “Mechayeh hametim” in the present era, thanks to improved telecommunications. However, where one was aware that his friend was in danger (e.g. his friend was captured in Entebbe), then it is appropriate to recite the blessing..."

Comment: Seth, odd because Rav Ovadiah's teshuva cited above contradicts that.

Comment: @DoubleAA let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2535/discussion-between-seth-j-and-double-aa)

Comment: I found the quote. It is Orchot Rabbeinu Book 1 Chapter 2 Paragraph 114 (which is page 93). There, he simply rules for a questioner by quoting the above referenced Mishna Berura and saying it applies to someone in Tel Aviv and his friend in Yerushalayim. So the Steipler really isn't adding much to the discussion.